# How to SELECT - UPDATE then copy the value to another table (In Bulk)

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a short link system for a mailing software I'm using,
I have 2 tables:

```
Table1 : t1_id, t1_campaign_id, t1_email_address, t1_email_text, t1_url
Table2 : t2_id, t2_code, t2_status
```

What I'm doing is generating shortcodes in Table2 via a cronjob, so I've more than 2M records,
When I want to send a new email, the system fills the Table1 with all the data except the t1_url.

I want a query that copy 1 t2_code to t1_url and change the t2_status to '1',
The t2_code should be used one time, and I can't use the t1_id = t2_id condition because some emails don't contain the short links.

I can achieve this easily with a PHP loop, but I'm dealing with big numbers here and I want something fast.

So, what I want to achieve is :

```
1 - SELECT t2_code FROM Table2 WHERE t2_status = '0';
2 - UPDATE Table2 SET t2_status = '1' WHERE t2_code = "[RETURNED VALUES FROM FIRST QUERY]"
3 - UPDATE Table1 SET t1_url = '[RETURNED VALUES FROM FIRST QUERY]' WHERE t1_campaign_id = '[Example: 1]'
```

SAMPLE:

```
- TABLE1
t1_id, t1_campaign_id, t1_email_address, t1_email_text, t1_url
'217', '327', 'john@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', ''
'218', '327', 'doe@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', ''
'219', '327', 'esys@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', ''

- TABLE2
t2_id, t2_code, t2_status
'2627', 'GtSu75s', '0'
'2628', 'TY8usk2', '0'
'2629', 'HDY2i9z', '1'
'2630', 'JEYSO6s', '0'
'2630', 'KjdU8n1', '1'
'2631', 'KSYZnc8', '0'
'2632', 'jd6sjc8', '0'
```

RESULT I WANT :

```
- TABLE1
t1_id, t1_campaign_id, t1_email_address, t1_email_text, t1_url
'217', '327', 'john@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', 'GtSu75s'
'218', '327', 'doe@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', 'TY8usk2'
'219', '327', 'esys@gmail.com', 'Hello How are you doing?', 'JEYSO6s'

- TABLE2
t2_id, t2_code, t2_status
'2627', 'GtSu75s', '1'
'2628', 'TY8usk2', '1'
'2629', 'HDY2i9z', '1'
'2630', 'JEYSO6s', '1'
'2630', 'KjdU8n1', '1'
'2631', 'KSYZnc8', '0'
'2632', 'jd6sjc8', '0'
```

Can anyone suggest a query or a method to this very fast?

Thank you.

Comment: The logic for the second update query is not clear, and you may want to add sample data.

Comment: UPDATE Table1 SET t1_url = '[RETURNED VALUES FROM FIRST QUERY]' WHERE t1_campaign_id = '[Example: 1]' - This will update the t1_url and set the value I get from SELECT query

Answer (score 0):

I would use an exists update query here:

```
UPDATE Table2 t2
SET t2_status = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table2 t1
              WHERE t1.t2_code = t2.t2_code AND t1.t2_status = 0);
```

The query you *might* want for the second update is:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.t2_code = t2.t2_code
SET
    t1.t1_url = t2.t1_url
WHERE
    t1.t2_status = 1 AND
    t2.t2_status = 0 AND
    t1.t1_campaign_id = 'some campaign';
```

Comment: Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "WHERE" at position 113)

Comment: Sorry, I switched the order of the `WHERE` and `SET` clauses.

Comment: What I want is to copy the value from Table2 to Table1

Comment: NIce.  Please add some sample data.

Comment: Ok, Sample added

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table2 SET t2_status = '1' WHERE t2_code in (SELECT t2_code FROM Table2 WHERE t2_status = '0');
```

I guess you need something like this. The same could be applied for the second update statement.